# How to display multiple numbers with varying decimal lengths in array, C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, output

I'm trying to associate numbers between two arrays, and one of the arrays contains 500 numbers. Some of the numbers contain 2 decimal places, while others contain 3. How do i read off the numbers as is.

I tried `printf("%.3f",floatvar);` but it only displayed correctly when the number DID have 3 decimal places. It however made up an added number for those that had only 2 decimal places.

How do I display a float as is, or make it so that if it only contains 2 decimal places it will just add a zero after like `4.23` would be read `4.230`.

I cant round because I have to calculate exact mean of percentages.

Comment: I just tried `printf("%.3f", 4.23);` and it is printing `4.230`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `printf("%g",floatvar);`?. Anyway, `printf("%.3f",floatvar)` should add a trailing 0 for numbers with 2 decimals though.

Comment: Using `%g` won't print trailing zeros, so `1.23` is printed thus, but `1.234` is printed thus.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that `%g` should print the number "as it is" in this case, with 2 or 3 decimals, as I understand is the goal of the question. Although, as the user accepts a solution that prints a trailing 0, and he already tried `%.3f`, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks. yes it was right in the first place. there was an error elsewhere in the program.